# Telegram Bulk Messaging Limitation

Tags: python, scripting, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

this Platform is really really helpful. My issue is that is it possible to send 500k promotional messages per day? I have the script ready using the API # and API ID using Telethon. But anytime i try to send Messages, the accounts get banned. Maybe it got banned because i was on the same IP Address while scraping the users and sending messages. But what I really need to know is that is it even Possible to send 500k messages in day, if yes:

1. How many Accounts are needed(where can I get these number of
   accounts from)?
2. Do I have to manually create accounts and receive
   OTP's for each or is there a script ready for that as well that I
   can implement?
3. What should be the duration between each messages and
   how many messages from one single account.
4. How to shuffle between accounts while send messages? Manually or is there again a script
   ready for it?

Please guys I really really need help. If not 500k how many can i send per day maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You can send up to 20 messages per second in the same chat on Telegram.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm aiming to send messages to different accounts not the same account.